# RSA Signature having public key as text not verified in java

Tags: java, php, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle

This issue is generated in continuation of past question [How to RSA verify a signature in java that was generated in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522859/how-to-rsa-verify-a-signature-in-java-that-was-generated-in-php) . That code work for simple text. But Now I have requirement for signing and verifying the text which also have a public key ( other than verification key ) in format.

```
text1:text2:exported-public-key
```

Example :

```
53965C38-E950-231A-8417-074BD95744A4:22-434-565-54544:MIIBCgKCAQEAxWg6ErfkN3xu8rk9WsdzjL5GpjAucMmOAQNeZcgMBxN+VmU43EnvsDLSxUZD1e/cvfP2t2/dzhtV6N2IvT7hveuo/zm3+bUK6AnAfo6pM1Ho0z4WetoYOrHdOVNMMPaytXiVkNlXyeWRF6rl9JOe94mMYWRJzygntiD44+MXsB6agsvQmB1l8thg/8+QHNOBBU1yC4pLQwwO2cb1+oIl0svESkGpzHk8xJUl5jL6dDnhqp8+01KE7AGHwvufrsw9TfVSAPH73lwo3mBMVXE4sfXBzC0/YwZ/8pz13ToYiN88DoqzcfD3+dtrjmpoMpymAA5FBc5c6xhPRcrn24KaiwIDAQAB
```

PHP Code :

```
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$keysize=2048;
 $pubformat = "CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS1";
 $privformat = "CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS8";
$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS8);
$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS1);
$d = $rsa->createKey($keysize);
 $Kp = $d['publickey'];
 $Ks = $d['privatekey'];

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS8);
$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS1);
$d = $rsa->createKey($keysize);
$Kver = $d['publickey'];
$KSign = $d['privatekey'];

$plainText = "53965C38-E950-231A-8417-074BD95744A4:22-434-565-54544:".$Kp;

// Signing
$hash = new Crypt_Hash('sha256');
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();    
$rsa->loadKey($KSign);
$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
$rsa->setHash('sha256');

$signature = $rsa->sign($plainText);
$signedHS = base64_encode($signature);

// Verification

$signature = base64_decode($signedHS);
$rsa->loadKey($Kver);
$status = $rsa->verify($plainText, $signature);

var_dump($status);
```

JAVA Code

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
//import java.util.Base64;
//import java.util.Base64.Decoder;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class VerifySig {

    public static RSAPublicKey fromPKCS1Encoding(byte[] pkcs1EncodedPublicKey) {
        // --- parse public key ---
        org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey pkcs1PublicKey;
        try {
            pkcs1PublicKey = org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey
                    .getInstance(pkcs1EncodedPublicKey);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Could not parse BER PKCS#1 public key structure", e);
        }

        // --- convert to JCE RSAPublicKey
        RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(
                pkcs1PublicKey.getModulus(), pkcs1PublicKey.getPublicExponent());
        KeyFactory rsaKeyFact;
        try {
            rsaKeyFact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("RSA KeyFactory should be available", e);
        }
        try {
            return (RSAPublicKey) rsaKeyFact.generatePublic(spec);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Invalid RSA public key, modulus and/or exponent invalid", e);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        String pkey = "MIIBCgKCAQEA+8fKYCT4QiFUdsJ7VdF4xCkVmq/Kwc/10Jl3ie6mvn8hEsC3NAtMJu+Od12gyWYsS0zBDiQ8h2pGZ7p4uWqenc01dRRrq+g968zmoCKPUllPUuR6v9o+wYTX/os4hgaQSBg7DQn4g3BEekcvyk6e6zAMvuhHjeqnrinhCMFgJUhFL8zFNoyaH559C0TNbR6BTKzOoikah8cKhu4UOga0tWDC0I2Ifus/sHOwVaOBkDFIzD6jBxDH/QF8FsrLLTocuIb7Y6lVxFPPtgiUJku6b7wKExV0bPJvm6/Xhv1GX1FpMrA0Ylzj5IFviuviwgo534EcZQ/Hx3aIf4oPG8jVTQIDAQAB";
        byte[] dpkey = Base64.decodeBase64(pkey);
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = fromPKCS1Encoding(dpkey);
        String plainData = "53965C38-E950-231A-8417-074BD95744A4:22-434-565-54544:MIIBCgKCAQEArszIunGg3ievJOpgesYQsp3nPGgrW+3VwkivkkktOXUBRzb3G3mZzidEjG6LxNe/rrNe0UczmnSHQoSBxJCHyUnCWNfScBD66CFG4hLo5Z1gxrP8D2M2lCa6ap2PWcsKiWqlu38EinMeBjBvB4aYpF7+FkFy64ObxR4pfVZxnxradkD0HvvMPLMbyeHxeGqYf8orERf9jfuKTdY8V44rxht2D2fg2WhB1+XL0JulsPvgOaSK3RPnwi+RQAJbihCIh5Zznn0KQCs5pIWoT3XKe1DMpQuEmphSOY9ZUg3AwlOrpRV+565x6GCSc615/6nowmqKzE4T7qT5nbH+ctiEHQIDAQAB";
        String data = "iD96rNeR51BF2TUZSaw+QhW8SnsMXE5AdJiDVmJk6LL55jC26PBCnqXrFo2lsQt8aWRsZc0bHFGCcuIbhHA+Duo1/PwrxTqC5BZFL/frqsRSVa+vpvGEnj3xe4iImTEasMicQzzaAG9IWIgkRZ272lUZ8PqdtTuqAsRIwir6fEsfVs5uIErEWM18R4JxlFBc3LDIjFOFemEPSVIEBHwWht1c/CrdTtxPRIiugEb1jdofEBUNcWPZgfvApVx5+0aS9WTl31AY+RMlvp+13P/FQgAMnH9rvBdopRIVsZUNlMf8AOE2afhLPfOgx+41rzCB2wGCrRGELbml466WJ3wYNQ==";
        byte[] ciphertext = Base64.decodeBase64(data);
        System.out.println(new String(plainData.getBytes(), UTF_8));
        verifyBC(publicKey, plainData, ciphertext);
        System.out.flush();
    }

    private static void verifyBC(PublicKey publicKey, String plainData,
            byte[] ciphertext) throws Exception {
        // what should work (for PKCS#1 v1.5 signatures), requires Bouncy Castle provider
        //Signature sig = Signature.getInstance( "SHA256withRSAandMGF1");
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance( "SHA256withRSA");
        sig.initVerify(publicKey);
        sig.update(plainData.getBytes(UTF_8));
        System.out.println(sig.verify(ciphertext));
    }
}
```

It not gave any error but just return false when using public key in plainText. If try after removing with public key, It works and return true.

PHP is working fine and signature is verified in all cases.

I suspecting if java is unable to verify data having base 64 text/public key as text ?

UPDATE : I compare binary bytes of both two times and result show minor difference.

First Case

1. PHP -> ��#C:���sQ
2. JAVA -> ��/#C:���sQ

Second Case

1. PHP -> ��]Q0l�O+
2. JAVA -> ��]Q0l�

If php base64 is not compatible with apache base 64 ?

Comment: Where do you base 64 encode the public key in the PHP code? Or is the public key automatically encoded as base 64?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, Yes public/private key is automatically encoded by library. It is file exportable version.

Comment: You should try and binary compare the input of the signature generation function. It could be something as simple as a different line ending.

Comment: Checkout bytes before base 64 and compare them two different case and each have minor difference.

Comment: *I compare binary bytes of both two times* - which byte arrays exactly did you compare?

Comment: Could you print out that binary using the Hex class from Bouncy? If you just print binary then we get hard to read strings. Again, the input to the signature generation function please.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, more frustration. Hex is same for both php and java `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`

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, On java side i used custom code from internet, `public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] b) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(b.length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
          int v = b[i] & 0xff;
          if (v < 16) {
            sb.append('0');
          }
          sb.append(Integer.toHexString(v));
        }
        return sb.toString().toUpperCase();
      }` while on php bin2hex core function used.

Comment: Have you also provided the hash over the plaintext (instead of the plaintext itself) in PHP mode? The code may not hash itself although it's common for crypto libraries that it does. The Java code will certainly calculate the hash itself.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, No, I apply bin2hex function on signature bytes like `echo strtoupper(bin2hex($signature));`. which is infact binary data. I did not change behavior or program.

Comment: Since the hex codes are identical I'm thinking about some kind of string encoding problem maybe? After all, in your java code you explicitly specify UTF8.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty debugging your problem since I don't have a the key you used to generate that signature. However, when I run the PHP code, I'm noticing that $Kp contains a key wrapped in -----BEGIN/END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----. When I use the PHP script to export the key as a line of base64, it works. See https://gist.github.com/robinmj/8a3d2770357a5f911282

Comment: @robinj, Yes i found issue after compare your code with my code, I am signing plainText variable having unformatted (comments, new line chars) public key, While you formatted the plainText. As I provide formatted plainText to java code, So that not worked there. You can post answer for same, So I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run the PHP code, I'm noticing that the `$Kp` variable contains a key in the wrong format:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAqCJ/2E+YZvXJyabQmi0zZlaXXGbfXHt8KYS27i+PAJKBODmevTrS
w59S5AOy2l7lB4z5mYHuwdT6bm6YYXgE0gnoX/b2L65xdD9XtlenS4Zm15TVTdR5
zde4nBa0QPKfhFvthOmdPr9xDhDb8Rojy/phX+Ftva33ceTXoB+CtLyidMWbQmUh
ZufnI7MwIOPAIzXNJJ85eyUjBdoNMwlAPZo9vYQWeiwYGyP1fjQwEWZgjCH/LJjl
sNR1X9vp5oi8/4omdnFRvKLpkd5R7WMmMfAyAXe7tcfMSXuVAgMWEj9ZG0ELpXbG
S3CK6nvOp2gFF+AjHo9bCrh397jYotE3HQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

When I strip out all the extra formatting and export the key as a single line of base64, it works.

PHP code:

```
function extract_key($pkcs1) {
    # strip out -----BEGIN/END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----, line endings, etc
    $temp = preg_replace('#.*?^-+[^-]+-+#ms', '', $pkcs1, 1);
        $temp = preg_replace('#-+[^-]+-+#', '', $temp);
        return str_replace(array("\r", "\n", ' '), '', $temp);
}

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$keysize=2048;
 $pubformat = "CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS1";
 $privformat = "CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS8";
$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS8);
$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS1);
$d = $rsa->createKey($keysize);
 $Kp = $d['publickey'];
 $Ks = $d['privatekey'];


$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS8);
$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS1);
$d = $rsa->createKey($keysize);
$Kver = $d['publickey'];
$KSign = $d['privatekey'];

file_put_contents("pub_verify_key.txt",extract_key($Kver));

$plainText = "53965C38-E950-231A-8417-074BD95744A4:22-434-565-54544:".extract_key($Kp);

file_put_contents("plain.txt",$plainText);

// Signing
$hash = new Crypt_Hash('sha256');
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();    
$rsa->loadKey($KSign);
$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
$rsa->setHash('sha256');

$signature = $rsa->sign($plainText);

$signedHS = base64_encode($signature);

file_put_contents("signedkey.txt", $signedHS);

// Verification

$signature = base64_decode($signedHS);
$rsa->loadKey($Kver);
$status = $rsa->verify($plainText, $signature);

var_dump($status);
```

Java code:

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class VerifySig {

    public static RSAPublicKey fromPKCS1Encoding(byte[] pkcs1EncodedPublicKey) {
        // --- parse public key ---
        org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey pkcs1PublicKey;
        try {
            pkcs1PublicKey = org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey
                    .getInstance(pkcs1EncodedPublicKey);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Could not parse BER PKCS#1 public key structure", e);
        }

        // --- convert to JCE RSAPublicKey
        RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(
                pkcs1PublicKey.getModulus(), pkcs1PublicKey.getPublicExponent());
        KeyFactory rsaKeyFact;
        try {
            rsaKeyFact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("RSA KeyFactory should be available", e);
        }
        try {
            return (RSAPublicKey) rsaKeyFact.generatePublic(spec);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Invalid RSA public key, modulus and/or exponent invalid", e);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    String pkey = fromFile("pub_verify_key.txt");
        byte[] dpkey = Base64.decodeBase64(pkey);
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = fromPKCS1Encoding(dpkey);
        String plainData = fromFile("plain.txt");
        String data = fromFile("signedkey.txt");
        byte[] ciphertext = Base64.decodeBase64(data);
        System.out.println(new String(plainData.getBytes(), UTF_8));
        verifyBC(publicKey, plainData, ciphertext);
        System.out.flush();
    }

    private static void verifyBC(PublicKey publicKey, String plainData,
            byte[] ciphertext) throws Exception {
        // what should work (for PKCS#1 v1.5 signatures), requires Bouncy Castle provider
        //Signature sig = Signature.getInstance( "SHA256withRSAandMGF1");
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance( "SHA256withRSA");
        sig.initVerify(publicKey);
        sig.update(plainData.getBytes(UTF_8));
        System.out.println(sig.verify(ciphertext));
    }

    private static String fromFile(String filename) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(8000);
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File(filename));
            int c;
            while((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
                builder.append((char)c);
            }
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```